# SQL Null: Preferred way of distinguishing between unknown and no value

Tags: sql, null

Suppose I have a simple table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(40),
    born DATE,
    died DATE
);
```

Both the `born` and `died` dates are optional, so they can contain `NULL`.

Presumably authors who haven’t been born yet, won’t make it into the table, so the obvious way to interpret `NULL` would be that the date is unknown.

However, there is some ambiguity with the `died` date. A null could imply that the date is unknown, or that the author has yet to die.

What is the preferred way allow for both an unknown date and an event which has not yet occurred?

For what it’s worth, I routinely use PostgreSQL, MySQL/MariaDB and SQL Server, so this question isn’t specific to a particular DBMS.

Comment: IMHO The only way is using two fields 'died' (boolean) and 'date_of_death' (date)

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would be to add a new column `deceased` which indicates whether or not a given author has expired.  This frees your `died` date field from being responsible for whether an author has died.  Under this design, if an author has not yet died (`deceased` is false), then we don't care about the date of death.  And if an author has died, then a `NULL` value would only mean that the date really is unknown.

Comment: The problem with this is that the columns are no longer independent, and that it would be possible to have someone who is `deceased`, but `died` date, or who is _not_ deceased, but does have a `died` date.

Comment: @Manngo Inconsistencies like are only possible if your application logic allows it.  Sticking with just a `died` date field won't work for the reasons you already highlighted.

Comment: @Manngo: you can always create a check constraint to avoid that

Comment: If `deceased` were false, then you should not care what `died` is.  Typically people only live and die once (the cast of Twilight being notable exceptions), so I think your concern is not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to remove the `died` column and add the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE deaths (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES authors(id),
    died DATE
);
```

In this case, no record could imply that the author has not died, while a `NULL` in `died` would imply that the author has died, but the date is unknown.

The data data could then be extracted as follows:

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.name, a.born,
    CASE WHEN d.id IS NULL THEN 'living' ELSE coalesce(d.died,'unknown') END
FROM authors a LEFT JOIN deaths d ON a.id=d.id;
```

The `d.id` column is used to determine whether there is a matching row, otherwise the author is considered living. If there is a matching row, the result is either the `died` date or a coalesced alternative.

Comment: Not a bad solution +1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your comment. I see that it creates problems with a `JOIN`, as I would get `NULL` when there is  no matching row. I also should make this a one-maybe join (a one-zero/one). I shouldn’t do this when I’m about to go to bed.

Comment: Yeah I've gotten nailed posting stuff while half asleep.  Your solution seems reasonable though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have worked out the problem of the one-maybe relationship and the unmatched rows … Everything’s clearer after a good night’s sleep.

Answer (score 1):

This elaborates on Tim's answer.  I think the best approach is:

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(40),
    isDead int not null,  -- well, could be a bit or boolean or tinyint
    bornDate DATE,
    diedDate DATE,
    constraint chk_authors_isDead check (isDead in (0, 1)),  -- valid values
    constraint chk_authors_isDead_diedDate check (isDead = 1 or diedDate is NULL),
    constraint check_authors_bornDate_diedDate check (bornDate <= diedDate)  -- you might want to require that they are actually old enough to have written somthing
);
```

This code validates the following conditions:

- The new `isDead` column only takes on the values of 0 and 1.
- When `DiedDate` is not `NULL`, then `isDead` is 1.
- The author is born before they died.

Check constraints are standard SQL and supported by most databases -- but not alas by MySQL.